# How to import ixiatcl module after executing dependent bash commands in a python script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have dependency on 2 bash commands before importing modules.
When I execute below 2 commands on bash and then enter into python, I am able to import the module without any error.

```
-bash-4.2$ source /root/.profile 
-bash-4.2$ export PYTHONPATH=$IX_PY:$PYTHONPATH
-bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  3 2016, 22:05:29) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ixiatcl import IxiaTcl
>>>
```

But when I am trying to keep exact above things in my script, it doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print commands.getoutput("source /root/ixia/.profile")
print commands.getoutput("export PYTHONPATH=$IX_PY:$PYTHONPATH")
from ixiatcl import IxiaTcl
```

I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named ixiatcl
```

Can someone please suggest me a way to import this module considering dependency on 2 bash commands in a script?

Comment: It looks like you are setting path to this module. What do you think about use virtualenv? I think that it should solve your problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of `.profile` script here?

Comment: .profile has some environment variable and export statements, but looks like sourcing that also wont work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the Python path, you can insert the value of the `IX_PY` environment variable in the `sys.path` like this:

```
import sys
import os

IX_PY = os.environ['IX_PY']
sys.path.insert(0, IX_PY)

from ixiatcl import IxiaTcl
```

Comment: even after setting all environment variables this way, I couldn't import the module, if I enter into `python` with `pexpect.spawn`, I am able to import but not outside `python`, not sure what is still missing.

Comment: Your `.profile` activate a virtualenv or change your Python path. To call this script you need to use the right Python executable by giving the full path to the Python executable.

Comment: I do need to change `PYTHONPATH` in order to import the module. Can you please let me know how exactly I can source it?

Comment: No, there is no need to "source" a Python script. You need to know the path to the Python executable and call it like this: `/path/to/python your_script.py`.